# Managing releases on github & CDN

Tags: git, release, cdn

I try to learn how to work with releases on github.
I tried to do that with a simple project:

- I created 'v1.x' branch with some files and new release with 'v1.0.0' tag.
- Then I changed one of the files and created a new release with 'v1.0.1' tag.
  I checked it with CDN link and it works well for me. (@1.0 shows all the changes, @1.0.0 shows the first version without the changes).

But I'm not sure how I should work now? Will I need to create a new release after any change? (even if it's a tiny fix?)

When should I change the version (branch and tag) to v2.0 or v1.1?

And last thing, I tried another case with inner folders in my project:

- I created folder_01 in my repo and then created a release with v1.0.0 tag.
- After that, I created folder_02 in the same repo and created a release with v1.0.1 tag.
  But the CDN link with @1.0 show me just the first folder.

Where am I wrong?

I hope it's clear enough, I just want to understand how to work correct with releases on git and cdn links.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i manage the tags and versions:

Firstly, the the tag generation is done only when the `master` branch is updated. Then the following commands:

Merge develop into the master branch and push to the repo.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge develop
$ git push
```

Tag the new version and push the version to the repo.

```
$ git tag
$ git tag -a "X.X.X" -m "Version X.X.X"
$ git push --tags
```